# How to write replacement information in MySQL if no value is post

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following PDO script that looks for the values.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare( ' INSERT INTO `table1` (`person`, `player`, `card)

VALUES (:person, :player, :card) ' );


$stmt->execute([
    'person' => $_POST['person'],
    'player' => $_POST['player'],
    'card' => $_POST['card']
]);
```

If the value for player for example is not posted, the value should automatically write the value `Nothing`.

How can this be implemented using MySQL and PDO?

Comment: Do you mean something like `$_POST['player']??'Nothing'`?

Comment: `'person' => empty($_POST['person']) ? 'Nothing' : $_POST['person']`

Comment: You could address this in the table creation script, creating default values for the fields without having to write PHP code to support this.

Comment: @JayBlanchard this requires a trigger too, inserting an empty string will insert an empty string, not the default value

Answer (score 0):

You can first check if the fields you are expecting have been set as shown below

```
if(isset($_POST['person'])){
    $person = $_POST['person'];
}else{
    $person = NULL;
}

if(isset($_POST['player'])){
    $player = $_POST['player'];
}else{
    $player = NULL;
}

if(isset($_POST['card'])){
    $card = $_POST['card'];
}else{
    $card = NULL;
}
```

Then you can follow up with the following to commit it.

```
$stmt->execute([
    'person' => $person,
    'player' => $player,
    'card' => $card
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done MySQL server-side too.

You can define a default value for a specific field, and then, use a trigger that will use the default value instead of an empty string/null value :

```sql
CREATE TABLE test
(
  foo VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Nothing'
);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER SetDefault
BEFORE INSERT
ON test
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
    IF NEW.foo = '' OR NEW.foo IS NULL THEN -- In your case, NEW.person instead of NEW.foo
        SET NEW.foo =
        (
           SELECT COLUMN_DEFAULT
           FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
           WHERE table_schema = 'schema_name'
             AND table_name = 'test'
             AND column_name = 'foo'
        );
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

INSERT INTO test VALUES (''), (NULL);

SELECT * FROM test;
```

This outputs :

```
 foo
---------
 Nothing
 Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use null-coalescing operator to define the default values in case nothing is passed to your application in POST

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO table1(person, player, card) VALUES(:person, :player, :card)');

$stmt->execute([
    'person' => $_POST['person'] ?? 'nothing',
    'player' => $_POST['player'] ?? null,
    'card' => $_POST['card'] ?? null
]);
```

If you want to also specify the default value if the posted value is an empty string you can use ternary operator. e.g. `empty($_POST['person']) ? 'nothing' : $_POST['person']`

Answer (score -1):

Test if it is posted (isset()) and if so, test for empty string (strlen())

```
$player = (isset($_POST['player']) && 
           strlen($_POST['player'])>0 )?$_POST['player']:"Nothing";
$stmt->execute([
    'person' => $_POST['person'],
    'player' => $player,
    'card' => $_POST['card']
]);
```

Comment: So I would implement $player right after the query correct?

Comment: @HenryPinston Yes, 'implement' sounds like it is a lot, but it is just a test. Get the value from $_POST superglobal, and when it isn't there or is empty, give a replacement value ('Nothing')

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Add more validation and sanitize input.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="person" placeholder="Person Name"/>
            <input type="text" name="player" placeholder="Player Type"/>
            <input type="text" name="card" placeholder="card Type"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>


<?php 

//I have the following PDO script that looks for the values.

try{
    $db = new pdo("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8","root","");
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    if(!empty($_POST["person"]))
    {
        $person = htmlspecialchars($_POST["person"]);
    }
    else
    {
        $person = "Nothing";  // use Null instead and make sure in your column Null value is allowed
    }

    if(!empty($_POST["player"]))
    {
        $player = htmlspecialchars($_POST["player"]);
    }
    else
    {
        $player = "Nothing";  // use Null instead and make sure in your column Null value is allowed
    }


    if(!empty($_POST["card"]))
    {
        $card = htmlspecialchars($_POST["card"]);
    }
    else
    {
        $card = "Nothing";  // use Null instead and make sure in your column Null value is allowed
    }

    $stmt = $db->prepare( ' INSERT INTO table1 (person, player, card) VALUES (:person, :player, :card) ' );

    $stmt->bindParam("person", $person);
    $stmt->bindParam("card", $card);
    $stmt->bindParam("player", $player);

    if($stmt->execute())
    {
        echo "Data successfully inserted";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "There was a problem";
    }   
}

?>
```

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` < why did you add that? Not for sql injection prevention I hope? If so, it doesn't do anything for it. A prepared statement is all that's needed.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Thanks for that input, yes it's an old habit.